# nodejs app on GoDaddy

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, web-hosting

My node app (with mongodb) is currently on Heroku. Now, I want my website to be hosted on GoDaddy instead (shared hosting I think "Linux Hosting with cPanel"). 
My questions is, am I on the right track here:

- Delete the app from heroku
- I will buy Economy "Linux Hosting with cPanel" on GoDaddy (I already have a domain name) Q: is this a share hosting plan ?
- I will follow this tutorial on Node-cgi [Node-cgi-tutorial](http://www.cgi-node.org/docs/cgi-node-on-godaddy-tutorial)
- I already have an SSL certificate so I think  I will be able to apply it here

I looked everywhere for something that guides me through this but couldn't find any. Most of the things I find are outdated (about GoDaddy not share hosting node apps). Thank you.

Comment: make sure it is working on godaddy first before deleting it, this should be the last step, even after switching the nameservers.

Comment: Thank you, if anyone has any input on that, please let me know

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I saw the at the end of the tut ( <? cgiNodeInfo() ?> ). I already have a ready website built using node. does this thing ( <? cgiNodeInfo() ?> ) means that I have to change somethings in my website code ?! please let me know. Also, are these the only steps I really have to do. I am so sorry to bother you. (it's just the fact that I'm really afraid that it doesn't work and I will be having this web hosting plan for no reason)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn ONE last question sorry, should I follow this tut [link](https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-up-nodejs-application-for-production-ubuntu-17352)  if I'm going to but this plan Economy Linux Hosting with cPanel $53.88 ? I hope you can help me here